# Error - Use of undeclared type 'Error'

Tags: swift

Im getting an error saying - Use of undeclared type 'Error' i cannot move on without solving this error, I have tried looking online numerous times, but it doesnt help, I am using swift 2, and xcode 7.3

Comment: post your code and the line that gives you this error

Comment: func authUI(authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't post info in comments.

Comment: ... Swift 2? You really need to update to 3. Or maybe just wait a few months and go straight to 4 while you're breaking everything anyway.

Comment: Anyway, IIRC in swift 2 it was `ErrorType` and only changed to `Error` in swift 3.

Comment: I have a really old macbook, and it wont let me update xcode

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, the protocol was named `ErrorType`, use that. `ErrorType` was renamed in Swift 3 to `Error` (for a while during 3 development it was `ErrorProtocol`, but I don't *think* that was ever released).

Answer (score -1):

First, check if you have import Foundation in your code, and do so if you haven't

```
import Foundation
```

Next, clean your problem through XCode and rebuilt it.

I can compile it correctly in my code as you can see here
[image]

Comment: I checked, and I do have import Foundatiom

Comment: `Error` is a part of the standard library, so `Foundation` doesn't need to be imported to use it.

Comment: @Hamish Thank you for the info, It's good to know.

Comment: thank you guys so much! this is helping